# What exactly is a grid-like topology according to the book Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, geometric-deep-learning, books, non-euclidean-data

I am reading this book called "[Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)" (by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville).

[On page 326](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html), in the first paragraph, it says:

> CNNs, are a specialized kind of neural network for processing data that has a known grid-like topology. Examples include time-series data, which can be thought of as a 1-D grid taking samples at regular time intervals, and image data, which can be thought of as a 2-D grid of pixel

Considering an image as a grid is completely intuitive. And, similarly, we can extend the logic to a 1-D time series.

But then what cannot be considered as having a grid-like structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Graphs](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11226/2444).

In [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), nodes and edges do not *usually* have a specified position/orientation: for example, we cannot say that node $A$ is to the right/left of node $B$ because edges do not typically have an orientation. In grid-like structures, like images, we could say that about pixels. In a graph, all we know is that nodes are connected to other nodes via some edges, which may have weights, but, again, no orientation.